# What does it mean that a sequence of functions is bounded in $L^1(I)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I = (0, 1)$ and $f_n : I \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of functions.

What does it mean that $f_n$ is bounded in $L^1(I)$? Does it mean that
$$\exists c>0 \;\; \text{such that} \;\; \|f_n\|_1 \leq c?$$

Thank you!

Comment: You are correct as long as you add the words "for all $n$".

Comment: $\|f_n\|_1 = \int_I |f_n(x)|\,dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n\in L^1$, then necessarily there exists $C_n>0$ such that $\|f_n\|_1\leqslant C_n$ (since by definition, each $f_n$ has a finite $L^1$-norm). If there exists $C>0$ such that $\|f_n\|_1\leqslant C$ for **all** $n$, then we say that $f_n$ is *uniformly bounded*.

Comment: I suppose that $C > 0$ exists. We can take $C = sup \;\; C_n$.

Comment: What if $\sup_n C_n=+\infty$?

Comment: Then we take $C = max \;\; C_n$

Comment: That would mean that the $f_n$ are not uniformly bounded :)